# Colors of base R plots have changed - can I revert to old palette?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have noticed that colors in my `base` R plots have changed. Please look at the e.g. the red color on my plot "`before`" (previous R version) and "`now`" (current R version, `4.0.0`).

Is there anything I can do to reset any possible settings (e.g., `par()` etc.) to revert colors to normal?

[image][image]

Comment: @akrun, Yes, I deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in colors is due to that the default color palette changed in `R 4.0.0`. You can revert to the old colors by using `palette("R3")`.

---

From the [release news](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000653.html):

> The `palette()` function has a new default set of colours (which
>         are less saturated and have better accessibility properties).
>         There are also some new built-in palettes, which are listed by
>         the new `palette.pals()` function.  These include the old default
>         palette under the name `"R3"`.

See also the blog post [A New `palette()` for R](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/11/21/a-new-palette-for-r/index.html)

---

Default color palette in `R 4.0.0`:

```
palette()
# [1] "black"   "#DF536B" "#61D04F" "#2297E6" "#28E2E5" "#CD0BBC" "#F5C710" "gray62"
```

Revert to old default palette, `"R3"`:

```
palette("R3")
palette()
# [1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray"
```

Change to current default again:

```
palette("default")
# or
palette("R4")

palette()
# [1] "black"   "#DF536B" "#61D04F" "#2297E6" "#28E2E5" "#CD0BBC" "#F5C710" "gray62"
```

---

[image]